# Terminating and restarting a process

Tags: python

Right now I have a program that I have linked with GitHub, the only way of well-applying changes to it is to kill the current outdated process and rerun it with the new changes. I created a function to run a script in another file because terminating the same file will stop everything. Is there a better way of doing this? Right now the problem is that the file doesn't start up again, it just terminates it but doesn't get it back up.

Function in `main.py`:

```py
def force_restart():  
    os.system("python core/force_restart.py")
```

`force_restart.py` file:

```py
import time
import subprocess
import os

output = ""
p = subprocess.run("pkill -f main.py", shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
output += p.stdout
time.sleep(2)   #Time to recover and kill task
os.system("python main.py")
print(output)
```

Comment: It's possible that killing the main process will kill the child process, your restart script.  I would suggest that you not kill the old process.  Rather, just start the new one and then immediately exit the old one normally.

Comment: This code is killing itself because the force restart program is a child of the main program, but the force restart is killing the parent process which in turn terminates itself.

Comment: I'm not surprised you're getting flaky results. `os.system()` doesn't return until the process returns, but in this case that process kills the one that started it (which is waiting for it to finish).

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the old process then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the new version of main.py, and then exit the old version of main.py normally, by just returning from your main code branch or by calling sys.exit. - there's no reason to force kill the old version. There's no reason that both versions can't be running at the same time as long as the old just quits after starting the new one.

You could do something like this:

```
def force_restart():  
    os.system("python main.py")
    sys.exit(0)
```

On Linux and Mac, it doesn't matter if you've move or delete the original version of `main.py` after starting the old version of the app.  Linux will deal with that by keeping the old file so long as some process, in this case the initial version of the program, is still referring to that file.